# Replacing a switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I was going to replace the switch in my son's room with a regular single pole toggle switch, and I came across this. (see pictures).

Can I use the single pole toggle switch, and if so, how do I wire it?

Thanks for any points in the right direction.

[image: ][1]]

[image]

Comment: Why are you replacing this switch? Isn't it a single pole switch?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use the single pole toggle switch,

Yes

> and if so, how do I wire it?

The same way that one is wired.

All they did was attach two hot wires to the top terminal so they didn't have to make a joint.

The red wire should be the switched hot wire to the light.

Good luck and stay safe!